# Antlr 4 in python not working as expected (trying to parse chapter and paragraph of a book)

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I want to create a very simple ANTLR4 parser (in Python) without listener and visitor, which takes as input the chapter and paragraph of a book in any order, and returns the `high_level` (chapter) and `low_level` (paragraph) of the entry, e.g. if I enter `2 a` or `a 2` it should print "*chapter 2, paragraph a*".

Here is my `Example.g4`

```
grammar Example;

text
    : paragraph ;

paragraph
    : high_level (WS low_level)?
    | low_level WS high_level
    ;

low_level
    : 'a' | 'b'  | 'c'  ;

high_level
    : '1'  | '2'  | '3';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ ;
```

I do this in my terminal
`java -jar ~/antlr-4.8-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 -no-listener -no-visitor Example.g4`

which generates two python files, and then I wrote the following python script

```
from antlr4 import *
from ExampleLexer import ExampleLexer
from ExampleParser import ExampleParser


def main():
    while True:
        text = InputStream(input(">"))
        lexer = ExampleLexer(text)
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser = ExampleParser(stream)
        tree = parser.text()
        query = tree.paragraph()
        low_level = query.low_level()
        high_level = query.high_level()
        print(f"chapter {high_level}, paragraph {low_level}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, if I then run it and input `2 a`, I get this
`chapter [10 8], paragraph [12 8]`

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please? I don't understand the numbers in square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just some debugging information displayed by the `RuleContext` (from which your generated `Low_levelContext` and `High_levelContext` classes extend). In your case, the rule's `invokingState` and `parentCtx` are displayed.

Have a look at the source:

```py
class RuleContext(RuleNode):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.toString(None, None)

    ...

    def toString(self, ruleNames:list, stop:RuleContext)->str:
        with StringIO() as buf:
            p = self
            buf.write("[")
            while p is not None and p is not stop:
                if ruleNames is None:
                    if not p.isEmpty():
                        buf.write(str(p.invokingState))
                else:
                    ri = p.getRuleIndex()
                    ruleName = ruleNames[ri] if ri >= 0 and ri < len(ruleNames) else str(ri)
                    buf.write(ruleName)

                if p.parentCtx is not None and (ruleNames is not None or not p.parentCtx.isEmpty()):
                    buf.write(" ")

                p = p.parentCtx

            buf.write("]")
            return buf.getvalue()

    ...
```

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/RuleContext.py

You didn't explain what you wanted to display, but I guess the text the rules matched, in which case you can do this instead:

```
print(f"chapter {high_level.getText()}, paragraph {low_level.getText()}")
```

Comment: This was indeed what I was looking for. Thank you very much for pointing this out!